# Programmable parameter change of Pro/E simulation by using Excel VBA , Matlab, Labview or Pro/E own function

Tags: modeling, simulation, matlab, labview

Now, I've been conducting beam simulation by using Pro/E.

I would like to change payload(force) of beam step by step, and then plot the relation between deflection and payload(load range : 50kg to 500kg, step size : 25kg).

But, this task is too much time consuming, so that I would like to use a programming skill.

At the first time, I checked matlab-Pro/E interface, and I realized I can do something with SimMechanics tool.

But, unfortunately, my computer doesn't have the SimMachanics license.

So, I've been looking for other ways.

My computer has labview and MS-office as a programming language, as well as matlab.

Could I programmably change payload by using these programming languages without additional charged tool like SimMechanics?

If it is possible, Could anyone give me something like source code, documents or helpful site addresses?

If Pro/E provides desired function, it would be great. In that case, I don't need to make a program.

Comment: An important question would be if Creo has an accessible API through your license? Or are you asking for recommendations of simulation software (which we don't provide here)?

Comment: Not recommendation, I just want to get sharing eaperience.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to export the Pro|E/Creo model to a external FEA application and do it there. At the same time it makes me wonder a bit, if your load position stays the same and your assuming the material is deforming linearly then doubling load is just going to double the deflections. Seems a bit pointless to recalculate given that this linearity and small deflections are assumed by your FE solver. See the results you get just assume the shape is a linear spring.

Scripting with VBA is certainly possible if you have the VB API installed. The VB API is disabled by default so you need to go and activate it first. This is explained in length in the VB API folder under your install (it is in my experience not installed by default nearly anywhere). It is good to know that VB API is actually a COM bridge so it works fine in any COM capable language like C# ane python.

However to my knowledge there are no API calls for the wizard so you would need to go trough the screenscraping route.

Comment: Thank you for answer. As you mentioned, deformation was linear in  linear analysis. Now I am doing using the step analysis technique in the other way, something like 1st mode and deflection, according to beam's cross-section and thickness. Now, I am using Nastran ans matlab to do that. In my feeling, It was easier to control nastran input file than to control Pro/E by other programming platform.